# open GLES or canvas? (android)

Tags: android, opengl-es, canvas

I am making an app that is going to be on the market soon but i'm wondering, should I use Canvas or Open GLES? right now i have no idea about how to use open GLES. I am using canvas for about have a year and I heard that open GLES is better than canvas. I am making a 2d game and not a 3d game. should i use canvas or open GLES? if i should use the open GLES, can you give me a good tutorial on how to use it? and also how to do basic things like control the x and y in there or is it just like the canvas? please be specific because i have never experienced any kind of GL. Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6485667/android-live-wallpapers-opengl-vs-canvas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to have any more than 20 sprites you'll want to think about OpenGL ES. The following talks linked below explain the cut-offs and reasons why.

Good reference materials can be found at:

- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U4Bk5rmIpic
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7-62tRHLcHk
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cdvaPyq_eBU

which covers OpenGL ES compatibility issues and speed/performance issues.

You will have to choose between 1.1 or 2.0 - 1.1 is easier for 2d games in my opinion but 2.0 gives greater flexibility.