# Live Wallpaper: OpenGL or Canvas

Tags: android

I want to create a simple live wallpaper that has a background bitmap with few circles floating around. (just like [ICS Phase beam](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tribok.android.livewallpaper.icsclassic.lite&hl=en) wallpaper).

I've already done this in Canvas, and its not super fast and makes phone's scrolling slightly sluggish at times. Do you think I should migrate to OpenGL? Any tips on optimizing Canvas?

Comment: The more interesting question is what technique needs less energy.

Comment: iOS uses hardware acceleration all the time and still it gets a good talk time. So if you want to go for open gl then go for it. Also you can see if the performance improves with the current implementation by turning on hardware acceleration by default in the settings menu ICS.

Comment: @rekire Canvas is way more easier. But I want to build quality wallpaper. +Prakash locked Canvas (used in LWP) doesnt support hardware acceleration. Only way for LWP to be hardware accelerated is go the OpenGL way.

Comment: Check that : [Same Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6485667/android-live-wallpapers-opengl-vs-canvas)